# How to show there is an $S^4$ included in a simplicial complex?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex, morse-theory

A $\mathbb{Z}_2$-space is a pair $(T, \nu)$, where $T$ is a topological space and $\nu: T \rightarrow T$, called the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action, is a
homeomorphism such that $\nu \circ \nu= id_{T}$ . If $(T_1,\nu_1)$ and $(T_2, \nu_2)$ are $\mathbb{Z}_2$-spaces, a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map
between them is a continuous mapping $f : T_1 \rightarrow T_2$ such that $f \circ \nu_1 = \nu_2 \circ f$. The sphere $S^n$ is considered as a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-space with the antipodal homeomorphism $x \rightarrow -x$.

A simplicial $\mathbb{Z}_2$-complex is a simplicial complex $K$ with a simplicial map $\nu$ of $K$ into itself such that $\nu$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action on $K$.

I am working on a huge 35-dimensional simplicial $\mathbb{Z}_2$-complex that is very complicated. Let $B$ be this simplicial $\mathbb{Z}_2$-complex with the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action $\nu$. I want to show there is no (continuous) $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map from $B$ to $S^3$. In this text when we talk about an $S^4$, we mean a "hollow" $S^4$ such that $\nu(S^4)=S^4$. If a copy of $S^4$ (or any structure homeomorphic to an $S^4$) were included in $B$, then by Borsuk-Ulam Theorem, there would not be any $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map from $B$ to $S^3$. I applied a discrete Morse function on $B$ and got $B'$ which is simpler than $B$, and homotopy equivalent to $B$.

Since $B$ and $B'$ are homotopy equivalent, their homology groups $H_k$ are isomorphic and their Betti numbers $b_k$ are equal:
$$ H_k(B') \simeq H_k(B) \quad b_k(B')=b_k(B).$$

I am thinking to compute the homology group $H_4(B')$ and the Betti number $b_4(B')$ to get $H_4(B)$ and $b_4(B)$, and prove there exists a copy of $S^4$ included in $B$. I am not sure what homology group or Betti number show there exists an $S^4$ in $B$.

I guess that if I get $b_4(B)\neq 0$, I could conclude there is an $S^4$ included in $B$; or if $H_{4}(B)\neq 0$ and $b_4(B)= 0$, I could conclude there is no $S^4$ included in $B$ but still there is no $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map from $B$ to $S^3$.

Am I right? Are there any other ideas? My question is mostly about the homology groups. How do I realize that there is an $S^4$ in $B$ from its homology group (or Bettie number)?

---

Comment: All constant maps are continuous.I guess you have additional requirements.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @PaulFrost, let me note that if $B$ is the wedge $S^3 \vee S^4$, then there is a non-constant continuous map $B \to S^3$, while $B$ also contains a copy of $S^4$. The suspension of the Hopf map is an interesting continuous map $S^4 \to S^3$, too.

Comment: @Paul Frost, thanks for your comment and the examples. You are right, I missed an important requirement which was a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map instead of a continuous map. I edited my question. Please have a look. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @John Palmieri, thanks for the interesting examples. I edited my question. I meant a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map instead of a continuous map. Please have a look. Appreciate your help.

Comment: If $B$ consists only of two points (and $\nu$ swaps them), and I map them to antipodal points of $S^3$, isn't that a continuous $\mathbb Z_2$-map?

Comment: Do you need no copy of $S^4$, or do you actually need no copy of $S^4$ with its standard $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action? Following up on the comment by @MishaLavrov, if you have two disjoint copies of $S^4$ and $\nu$ swaps them, you can map them via constant maps to antipodal points of $S^3$. Also, if you have a copy of the ball $B^5$, then you have a copy of its boundary $\partial B^5 = S^4$ which may contribute nothing to homology or to Betti numbers.

Comment: If you have a 35-dimensional simplicial complex, then it will contain a 35-simplex, so it will contain all of its faces, including a 5-simplex. The faces of that 5-simplex form a 4-sphere.

Comment: @John Palmieri, thanks again for your comments. I think I need a hollow $S^4$ (an $S^4$ that is not a boundary of anything) that is equipped with its $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action, included in $B$. Then if $f: B \rightarrow S^3$ was a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map, then it is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map on $S^4$ too, $f|_{S^4}: S^4 \rightarrow S^3$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, thanks for your comment. You are right but my simplicial complex is too big and complicated that I cannot assume anything about its structure. I know it is connected, it has sub-complexes homeomorphic to "hollow" $S^2$ which are equipped with their $\mathbb{Z}_2$-actions. I simplified the complex to give it to the computer to compute the homology or Betti number, and from the result, I may figure out that there exists some "hollow" $S^4$ equipped with the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action.

Comment: By the way, you also can't use homology or Betti numbers to detect the presence of spheres. For example the 2nd homology group of a torus is $\mathbb{Z}$, but it contains no 2-sphere as a subcomplex.

Comment: I think your real question should be: what tools are there to show that there are no $\mathbb{Z}/2$-equivariant maps $B \to S^3$?

Comment: I downvoted because I object to how the question keeps changing as people raise issues with it. I think it is not well-formulated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that you can determine the lack of existence of a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-equivariant map $B \to S^3$ by knowing whether $B$ contains a "copy of $S^4$." For example, let $B$ consist of $S^3$ with its standard antipodal $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action, along with two copies of $S^4$, one glued to each "pole" $(0, 0, 0, \pm 1)$. Define a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-action on $B$ by, as I said, the antipodal action on $S^3$ and where $\nu$ interchanges the two copies of $S^4$. Then there is a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-equivariant map $B \to S^3$ which is the identity on $S^3$ and which sends each copy of $S^4$ to the pole where it's glued.

Comment: thank you so much for helping me with this question. I really appreciate it. You are absolutely right. What if I look for a copy of a hollow $S^4$ such that $\nu(S^4)=S^4$? If I can find such a thing, then if $f: B \rightarrow S^3$ was a $\mathbb{Z}_2$- map, then $f|_{S^4}: S^4 \rightarrow S^3$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-map which is a contraction by the Borsuk-Ulam Theorem.